# Direction rtl/lrt in safari

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, bidi

I wrote a webpage and its direction is `rtl` (right to left). Here is my `<html>` tag :

```
   <html dir="rtl">
```

I need 2 parts of the webpage to be written `ltr` (left to write), so I added `dir` attribute for this `div`

```
  <div dir="ltr">
```

It works on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, but not in Safari version 8.0 I in Mac OS X 10.10 on a virtual machine.

Why this is not working in Safari?

Could it be a CSS issue ?

Comment: version 8.0  I use safari in 10.10osx on vm

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSS direction property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) instead of the `dir` HTML attribute and see if it helps :

```
<div style="direction:rtl;">...</div>
```